# Executing Shell Scripts for Each IP Found in grep

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am currently working on script that will monitor our Access Points via SNMP. The problem is, how can I execute my snmp commands for each AP IP found in grep command. I have a text file that contains IPs:

```
O55 172.22.168.3
O55 172.22.168.8
O55 172.22.168.5
O55 172.22.168.6
O55 172.22.168.4
O55 172.22.168.7
546 172.22.98.3
546 172.22.98.4
546 172.22.98.5
546 172.22.98.6
546 172.22.98.7
546 172.22.98.8
546 172.22.98.54
```

now I am using this commands to find specific ID only, for this example, I am finding "O55".

```
grep "O55" O55.txt | awk '{print $2}' | sort
```

then the result will display only those IPs found in "O55" line.

```
172.22.168.3
172.22.168.4
172.22.168.5
172.22.168.6
172.22.168.7
172.22.168.8
```

now my problem is, how can I execute my snmpwalk commands for each of these IPs found? Can anyone give me an idea how to start the command? these commands are what I am using for snmpwalk commands only for one given ip only, I just don't know how to start a command for multiple IPs found.

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c Canopy 172.22.168.3 1.3.6.1.4.1.161.19.3.3.1.1
snmpwalk -v2c -c Canopy 172.22.168.3 1.3.6.1.4.1.161.19.3.1.3.3
```

to summarize all, the result I want is like this,

input BTSID ==> O55
then run the script, find O55 in `O55.txt`

```
O55 172.22.168.3
O55 172.22.168.8
O55 172.22.168.5
O55 172.22.168.6
O55 172.22.168.4
O55 172.22.168.7
```

then run `snmpwalk` commands, but each line of `snmpwalk` has a corresponding variables, example is:

`OID_A=snmpwalk -v2c -c Canopy "each_IP_of_O55" 1.3.6.1.4.1.161.19.3.3.1.1`
`OID_B=snmpwalk -v2c -c Canopy "each_IP_of_O55" 1.3.6.1.4.1.161.19.3.3.1.9`
`OID_C=snmpwalk -v2c -c Canopy "each_IP_of_O55" 1.3.6.1.4.1.161.19.3.1.4.1.49`

then the last result would be like:

`echo "${OID_A}   ||   ${OID_B}   ||   ${OID_C}"`

example of result is like this:

```
172.22.168.3   ||   CANOPY 11.0.2 AP-DES   ||   Receiving Sync
172.22.168.8   ||   CANOPY 11.0.2 AP-DES   ||   Receiving Sync
172.22.168.5   ||   CANOPY 11.0.2 AP-DES   ||   Receiving Sync
172.22.168.6   ||   CANOPY 11.0.2 AP-DES   ||   Receiving Sync
172.22.168.4   ||   CANOPY 11.0.2 AP-DES   ||   Receiving Sync
172.22.168.7   ||   CANOPY 11.0.2 AP-DES   ||   Receiving Sync
```

any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you. :)

Thank you for your help guys, somehow I've managed to made a script and the result is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks for your suggestions and inputs. this is a part of the script I made

```
 #!/bin/bash  
 BTSID="$1"  
 SNMPWALK='/usr/bin/snmpwalk'  
 SNMPOID='1.3.6.1.4.1.161.19.3'  

 echo "Query Time: `date "+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"`"  
 APIP=`grep ${BTSID} -i O55.txt | awk '{print $2}'`  
 for EACH in `echo ${APIP}`  
  do  
  SWVersion=`$SNMPWALK -v2c -c Canopy ${EACH} ${SNMPOID}.3.1.1 | awk '{print $4" "$5" "$6}' | sed 's/"//g'`  
  Sync=`$SNMPWALK -v2c -c Canopy ${EACH} ${SNMPOID}.1.3.3 | awk '{print $4" "$5}' | sed 's/"//g'`  
  Linkspeed=`$SNMPWALK -v2c -c Canopy ${EACH} ${SNMPOID}.3.1.9 | awk '{print $4" "$5" "$6}' | sed 's/"//g'`  

  echo "${EACH}  ||  ${SWVersion}  ||  ${Sync}  ||  ${Linkspeed}  ||  ${Confsrc}:${confsrc_v}
```

as what William Pursell said, "don't pipe grep to awk", but this script produce the result I need. If you have any suggestions on how to improve the part with grep piping awk, it's highly appreciated. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `awk`.  If you don't actually need the ips to be sorted, you can call your shell script directly from awk.  For example, if you want to run `/path/to/script $ip` for each ip address in the file that matches the "055" string in the first column:

```
awk '$1 == "055" { system( "/path/to/script " $2 )}'
```

The commands you are invoking are simple enough that it might be okay to call them directly rather than putting them in a script:

```
awk '$1 == "055" {
        system( "snmpwalk -v2c -c Canopy " $2 " 1.3.6.1.4.1.161.19.3.3.1.1")
        system( "snmpwalk -v2c -c Canopy " $2 " 1.3.6.1.4.1.161.19.3.1.3.3")
}' 055.txt
```

If you do actually need them sorted, it's probably simplest to pre-sort and do:

```
sort 055.txt | awk ...
```

Whatever you do, don't pipe `grep` to `awk`.  `awk` is perfectly capable of filtering the data.

If the value `055` is in the shell variable `BTSID`, you can pass the variable into awk using the syntax:

```
awk '$1 == m { system( "/path/to/script " $2 )}' m=${BTSID}
```

Comment: thank you for the swift response, well actually there are i think 40+ snmpwalk commands to execute on each ip, that's why I am putting them on a script. and also I am executing the script via VBA userform where the ID will be entered. also I will display the result of those commands in pattern. anyways, I'll try the commands you suggested. :)

Comment: i tried using your given commands, and the results are great, however, when I tried using a variable for the ID and OID, I'm getting an error upon running the script. here is the scenario:

i tried using variable
    `BTSID="$1"`  
    `SNMPWALK='/usr/bin/snmpwalk'`  
    `SNMPISO='1.3.6.1.4.1.161.19.3'`  

then I tried this code but resulted an error
`awk '$1 == "${BTSID}" {`  
        `system( "$SNMPWALK -v2c -c Canopy " $2 " ${SNMPISO}.3.1.1")`  
        `system( "$SNMPWALK -v2c -c Canopy " $2 " ${SNMPISO}.1.3.3")`  
`}' 055.txt`

Comment: You cannot pass shell variables like that to awk.  Awk is trying to match the first column with the literal string `${BTSID}` rather than the expansion of the shell variable.  However, you can do things like: `awk '$1 == d { ... }' d=$BTSID`

Comment: I got it now, tnx for the help Sir William. The shell is now working as expected. now if I wanted to set variables on each snmpwalk command, how can I set it? is it like this?

    `OID_A=system( "snmpwalk -v2c -c Canopy " $2 " 1.3.6.1.4.1.161.19.3.3.1.1")`
    `OID_B=system( "snmpwalk -v2c -c Canopy " $2 " 1.3.6.1.4.1.161.19.3.1.3.3")`

Comment: also how can I substitute the long line `1.3.6.1.4.1.161.19.3` with `oid` in the line where snmpwalk command is? so it when I write the commands it would be like this `oid.3.1.1` but will produce also the same result as with the long line.

Comment: Concatenate a string with a variable like this: `{ oid="1.3...."; system( "..." $2 " " oid ".1.4" ) }`  It's a bit kludgy, and you can use sprintf instead, but basically `oid ".1.4"` will expand to `"1.3...1.4"`.  This is why you need to explicitly add whitespace in side quotes to keep strings separate.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with SNMP, but a bash `read` call in a while loop in conjunction with [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) should be able to do the trick. Also, you should be able to lose the [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) command and let [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) handle the filtering as shown below

```
while IFS= read -r ip_addr; do
 snmpwalk -v2c -c Canopy "${ip_addr}" 1.3.6.1.4.1.161.19.3.3.1.1
 snmpwalk -v2c -c Canopy "${ip_addr}" 1.3.6.1.4.1.161.19.3.1.3.3 
done < <(awk '/055/ {print $2}' O55.txt | sort)
```

Comment: tnx for the prompt response, can you further explain what does IFS stands for? and how do i read the IP addresses in the file to execute the snmpwalk commands? I must admit that I am new to this linux world, and I am just trying to understand each of those commands as much as possible. somehow I can easily understand with little explanation. :)

Comment: +1 for combining process substitution, using IFS (Input Field Separator, the built in bash variable which sets the character which separates 'words' in the read) as part of the while condition. Personally, if the list of IPs does not need to be sorted I'd drop the ip_addr variable and go with `-c Canopy ${REPLY## *}` in the body. This is somewhat more obscure but avoids starting up `awk`.

Comment: I tried using your given commands, but it seems that it displays and process all the IPs listed in O55.txt, doesn't seem to filter O55 lines only.